# Can I run .NET core 1.0 app on server with framework 4.0?

Tags: c#, .net-core

The server runs windows server 2008 R2 that has .NET 4.0 framework as its highest supported version. I did see people commented that .NET core supports frameworks comes later than 4.5.

Comment: .NET Core doesn't need the .NET Framework. You can also publish "self-contained" .NET Core applications that don't require additional .net core runtime installations on the server.

Comment: It has prerequisites though.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can run it on Windows 2008 R2 if you install SP1 and the suitable Core Framework.

Supported Windows Version:

- Windows 7 SP1
- Windows 8.1
- Windows 10
- Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 (Full Server or Server Core)
- Windows Server 2012 SP1 (Full Server or Server Core)
- Windows Server 2012 R2 SP1 (Full Server or Server Core)
- Windows Server 2016 (Full Server, Server Core or Nano Server)

and your System should be up to date:
For Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 machines only:
Make sure that your Windows installation is up-to-date and includes hotfix KB2533623 installed through Windows Update.

You can find more information here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/windows-prerequisites
or you can read the release information form the differnt core versions on github.

Answer (score 0):

According to .NET Core documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/windows-prerequisites), you can target Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 on .NET Core.

You can also upgrade to .NET Framework 4.5.2 on Windows Server 2008, refer [this link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=42642).

If however, you cannot upgrade to .NET Framework 4.5 and above, I think you are out of luck. Refer [.NET Standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/library)

Answer (score 0):

.NET Core doesn't know about, or really interact with, .NET Framework.  Conversely, .NET Framework doesn't really know about, or interact with, .NET Core.  So this question is sort of like "can I put Photoshop on a machine which currently has mspaint, but not paint.net?".

.NET Core applications can either be published and run in a mode where they depend on a shared framework having been installed, which makes each individual application smaller but has a prerequisite.  Or, you can publish an application as everything it needs to run on some other machine as a "self-contained" or "standalone" application, which makes the application easier to run on an arbitrary machine (of the correct OS family) but at the expense of it being larger.

If you can't change the dependencies of the target machine at all, you want to go the self-contained route.  If .NET Framework 4.0 is the newest available ([even though it is out of support](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework_version_history#Overview)) because of an admin being concerned about upgrading shared dependencies then maybe you can get the .NET Core runtime installed, since it won't interact with .NET Framework, and then you can stick with the smaller footprint deployment.

For an explanation of self-contained vs framework-dependent (and how to do it), see 
https://www.hanselman.com/blog/SelfcontainedNETCoreApplications.aspx